# how to fetch a JSP page residing on a remote machine?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I'm looking for a way within Spring MVC to put my JSP pages in a remote machine and load them when I need them.

The reason I wanna do this is because my application received some page templates from users and I have to save them somewhere and load them dynamically when that page get requested! I was thinking if I want to put my users' JSPs pages inside my web-app on real time, It's not possible so I have two choice :

1) save it in a remote place and get reference to it while a request comes in

2) save them inside database which I think that's not good because the user page may have so many visitors ...

What solution you suggest ?

Comment: JSP pages can contain fragments of code. You are asking how to run arbitrary fragments of code provided by users and resident on some remote computer. This is a terrible idea for security and comprehension.

Comment: @Raedwald that is another concern, I also thought about that problem and the answer is JSOUP cleaner and validation

Answer (score 0):

Using unix? Maybe you could mount the remote server and create a symbolic link to `WEB-INF/jsp` directory to point to the remote mount.

Comment: Many application servers do not explode their deployment so this trick will not be portable.